# Upgraded eclipse cdt from Ganymede to Kepler - how to import my project?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'd like to use Kepler on a C project that was created on Ganymede (v3.4.1).
How do I import my project? Kepler has on option for importing C/C++ project settings, and expects an xml file, whereas the old project has .prefs files in .settings.

Comment: did you try: "file->import->general->Existing Projects into Workspace" thatś normally used to import a project directly. but i don't know if it works with ganymede projects.

Comment: thanks @user283078, that worked, and maybe it doesn't matter about the settings files.